# What is homotopy in $(\infty,1)$-categories (as weak Kan complexes)

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory

One of the peculiar (and somewhat appealing) features of quasi-categories is that many properties from ordinary category theory characterized equality are characterized by some form of homotopy (morphisms to a terminal object are homotopy equivalent instead of unique, associativity is up to homotopy, and so forth).

While I know what homotopy is in the sense given by any introductory algebraic topology textbook, and can generalize this to "some kind of congruence relation on morphisms" in a 1-category, **I'm not clear on what homotopy of $n$-cells in a quasicategory should be** and I can't seem to find a definition. Any pointers?

Comment: A homotopy between $n$-cells in a quasicategory is a special kind of $(n + 1)$-cell.

Comment: @ZhenLin - Do you know where I might find a general characterization of what kind of $(n+1)$-cell works as a homotopy?

Comment: You basically choose two faces of the $(n + 1)$-simplex to be the source and target and require the remainder to be degenerate in the appropriate sense. The case $n = 1$ is discussed in any introduction to quasicategories.

Comment: Hm, must have read right past it in Lurie...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you should take a look at the definitions of the right and left mapping spaces between two objects in a quasi-category.  The 0-simplices in this simplicial set are the morphisms, 1-simplices are the homotopies between morphisms (in the sense of Boardman and Vogt, see their construction of the homotopy category), and so on.  As Zhen Lin said, this should be covered in any introduction to quasi-categories.  Aside from Lurie I would highly recommend the course notes of Denis-Charles Cisinski, available on his web page.

Comment: Thanks! The trouble I think I'm having is that Lurie  explores alternate definitions of mapping spaces from versions of $\infty$-categories besides quasi-categories, and those are constructions I understand even less than simplicial sets (I read the first couple chapters of an algebraic topology textbook once...). So the associated version of homotopy doesn't necessarily get clearer. Following Zhen Lin's remarks I found a version that makes sense, except that I can't see the Kan complex structure on the mapping space :p

Comment: As a curiosity, is there anyone who has (as Lurie avoids doing) developed the general theory of $\infty$-bicategories (rather than just that of the small $(\infty,1)$-categories)?